# Adjective + 出す？

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, verbs, conjugations

Recently I watched this and the translator gives me something I didn't know.
I know that a verb + 出す means to start.....

> 走り出す - To start to run
>   逃げ出す - To start to escape
>   登り出す - To start to climb

But what I saw is 救い出してあげる (what it's root form is 救い出す, isn't it?)

So, the question. Does 出す have a different meaning when is next to an adjective い/な?

Thanks in advance for any help you can bring me! Cheers

Answer (score 8):

To add to @Locksleyu's answer, 出す in "the continuative form of a verb (動詞の連用形) + 出す" can mean either:

> ㋐ そうすることによって外や表面に現れるようにする意を表す。「しぼり―・す」「見つけ―・す」
>   to make something reveal/appear outside or on the surface by doing the action, eg 「しぼり**出す**」(squeeze **out**) 「見つけ**出す**」(find **out**)

or

> ㋑ その動作を始める意を表す。「降り―・す」「笑い―・す」
>   to start the action, eg 「降り出す」(start to fall/rain) 「笑い出す」(begin to laugh)

(Source: [「出す」 #４（動詞の連用形に付いて） in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/136563/meaning/m0u/))

The 出す in [救]{すく}い出す is used in the sense of ㋐, "to save/help (someone) **out** (of somewhere / trouble / difficult situation)", rather than "start to help."

Here are some more examples:

> ㋐:
>   [取]{と}り出す -- take out
>   [引]{ひ}き出す -- pull out
>   [呼]{よ}び出す -- tell (someone) to come; summon
>   [助]{たす}け出す -- help (someone out of...)
>   ㋑:
>   [泣]{な}き出す -- start to cry
>   [歩]{ある}き出す -- start to walk
>   [歌]{うた}い出す -- start to sing

(Some ~~出す compound verbs have both meanings, eg 逃げ出す can mean ㋐ get away from... / out of... ㋑ start running away)

Answer (score 4):

In your example 救い is not an adjective, but rather the pre-masu form of 救う, "to save". The grammar is the normal pattern of "pre-masu form" + "出す".

However, rather than thinking of 救い出す as meaning "to start to save", I think it's better to just think of it as a separate verb, as shown in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/38925/meaning/m0u/%E6%95%91%E3%81%84%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99/). Based on this dictionary definitions, it mostly means the same as 救う, except that 救い出す is used more to physical save someone, where as 救う can also mean in a metaphorical/spiritual sense (i.e. "save from sin").

Generally, adjectives are not used with the verb 出す to mean "begin to ~".

Comment: so here 救う changes to 救い in order to add 出す? as in 走る that changes inti 走り in order to add 出す and form 走り出す. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Using another verb with ~う, ending, 買う would change to 買いだす