# What does し mean here?

Tags: grammar

> 人間は持たざる時には人並みを求めるが、一度人並みになるや、今度は人との違いを求めだ**し**、人と同じ商品では満足できなくなるからだ

At first I thought し indicated reason, but からだ already indicates reason, so し here would be redundant.

Answer (score 4):

The `し` is just part of a normal conjugation of the verb `求め出す` -> `求め出し`. It would be clearer if it were written with the kanji for `出す`, but when combined with other verbs it's sometimes just written `だす` like it is here.

You can read more about verb+`出す` [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36118/adjective-%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95306/understanding-%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99-and-%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B-compound-verb-pairs), and a little about the criteria for using kanji or not in cases like this [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72344/kanjied-%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-vs-kananed-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-in-dasu-dashta-pattern).